# Pandas puts all data from a row in one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have another problem with csv. I am using pandas to remove duplicates from a csv file. After doing so I noticed that all data has been put in one column (preprocessed data has been contained in 9 columns). How to avoid that?

**Here is the data sample:**

```
39,43,197,311,112,88,47,36,Label_1
```

**Here is the function:**

```
import pandas as pd

def clear_duplicates():
    df = pd.read_csv("own_test.csv", sep="\n")
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)
    df.to_csv("own_test.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `sep`, because default separator is `,` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
def clear_duplicates():
    df = pd.read_csv("own_test.csv")
    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    df.to_csv("own_test.csv", index=False)
```

Maybe not so nice, but works too:

```
pd.read_csv("own_test.csv").drop_duplicates().to_csv("own_test.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: @piRSquared - Thanks.

Comment: the second option is nice!